# Cant change content on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame, which has a JPanel called `gamePanel` added to it. The game calls the method `renderPlayerInfo` multiple times after the main frame is set to visible. However, the panel does not change after the first time I call the method.

*renderPlayerInfo*

```
void renderPlayerInfo(JPanel gamePanel) {
        Font renderFontBold = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
        Font renderFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16);

        renderPanel.removeAll();
        System.out.println("e");

        int yRender = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel(null);
            playerPanel.setBounds(0, yRender, 300, 110);
            playerPanel.setBackground(new Color(204, 227, 199));

            JLabel playerLabel = new JLabel("Player " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
            playerLabel.setFont(renderFontBold);
            playerLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 18);

            JLabel playerToken = players.get(i).getPlayerToken(244, 0);
            playerPanel.add(playerToken);

            JLabel moneyIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("./res/money.jpg"));
            moneyIcon.setBounds(30, 40, 64, 32);
            playerPanel.add(moneyIcon);
            JLabel moneyAmount = new JLabel("£" + moneyFormatter.format(players.get(i).playerMoney));
            moneyAmount.setFont(renderFont);
            moneyAmount.setBounds(100, 48, 200, 18);
            playerPanel.add(moneyAmount);

            JPanel separatorPanel = new JPanel();
            separatorPanel.setBounds(0, 108, 300, 2);
            separatorPanel.setBackground(new Color(146, 159, 149));
            playerPanel.add(separatorPanel);

            playerPanel.add(playerLabel);
            renderPanel.add(playerPanel);

            if (i + 1 == playerTurn) {
                JLabel turnPointer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("./res/turnPointer.png"));
                turnPointer.setBounds(70, -12, 64, 64);
                playerPanel.add(turnPointer);
            }

            yRender += 110;
        }
        renderPanel.repaint();

        gamePanel.add(renderPanel);
        gamePanel.repaint();
    }
```

I tried adding `renderPanel.repaint()` but this does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Cant change content on a JPanel

It can.

But generally speaking, one would not achieve that in the way you are trying to do.  Instead of ripping out all of the components and replacing them with new, one would ordinarily update the models of the existing components so that when they are repainted, the view will be as you want.  For example, use `JLabel.setText()` instead of creating a whole new `JLabel`.  Of course, this does require you to keep references to the components you will want to update in a way that enables you to perform such modifications cleanly.  Under some circumstances, it might make sense to create custom components to help you with that.

Also, however, it is unclear from what context you are calling `renderPlayerPanel()`, but inasmuch as it modifies GUI components, it needs to run on the event dispatch thread.  If it's not running there already, then you can fix that by having the invoker(s) go through [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) or [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to run it.

> I tried adding renderPanel.repaint() but this does not seem to change anything.

Not surprising.  You're already repainting that panel's container; it has no additional effect to also repaint the panel directly.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on the event dispatch thread? I'm not too sure what that is? Is that only code that runs in the Main class?

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) section.

Comment: @AtomicPeanut, in any program with an AWT (including Swing) GUI, there is one thread, separate from the application's main thread, on which all AWT events are fired.  This is called the "event dispatch thread".  In order for such a program to be properly synchronized, substantially all manipulation of AWT / Swing components must also occur on this thread.  Often that's an issue only for initial GUI setup, because GUI-driven behavior happens on the EDT automatically (via events), but if other threads want to interact with the GUI then they need to do as I describe in this answer.

Comment: @AtomicPeanut, it sounds like you would really benefit from going through Oracle's Swing tutorial, to which Gilbert has provided a link.  It's pretty good, and there seem to be a lot of holes in your foundation that it could fill.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will take a look through the tutorial.

Comment: I have made these changes, the method now runs in the event dispatch thread, and I have made custom classes for the components. However, my problem still remains.

Comment: I'm sorry you're still having trouble, @AtomicPeanut.  Unfortunately, we never had much to go on here, and now we have nothing.  You should reduce your problem to a [mre] and present that in a new question.  The exercise may even lead you to discover the issue for yourself.